# How to use relationships in CoreData properly?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm programming an app where I need a relationship from one CoreData entity to another. I'm building a learning app with flashcards. However, on the process of adding data to CoreData entities I receive errors:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'FlashSets'

> Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'addToCards'.

Here's DataController functions for handling data for CoreData entities:

```swift
func add(term: String, definition: String, tag: String, date: Date, set: FlashSets, context: NSManagedObjectContext)  {
    let data = FlashCardData(context: context)
//    flashCardData.flashSet = flashSet
    data.id = UUID()
    data.definition = definition
    data.term = term
    data.tag = tag
    data.date = date
    data.set = set
    save(context: context)
}

func addName(name: String, date: Date, cards: [FlashCardData], context: NSManagedObjectContext)  {
    let data = FlashSets(context: context)
    data.name = name
    data.date = date
    data.cards = NSSet(array: cards)
    save(context: context)
}
```

Here's a view where I'm adding user's data in CoreData:

```
let newSet = dataController.addName(name: name, date: Date(), cards: [], context: managedObjectContext)
                        
    dataController.savedFlash = []

    // Create new FlashCardData for each term/definition/tag in viewModel.termdefpairs and associate with newSet
    for testForm in viewModel.termdefpairs {
        let card = dataController.add(term: testForm.term, definition: testForm.definition, tag: testForm.tag, date: Date(), set: newSet, context: managedObjectContext)
        dataController.savedFlash.append(card)
        newSet.addToCards(card)
    }
    dataController.save(context: managedObjectContext)
    
    
    isShowingSet = true
    dismiss()
}) {
    Text("Save")
    NavigationLink(destination: SetView(flashCardData: _flashCardData), isActive: $isShowingSet) {
        EmptyView()
    }
})
```

CoreData entities, in FlashCardData set relationship is One-to-One, if FlashSets cards is One-to-Many:

[image: CoreData entities, in FlashCardData set relationship is One-to-One, if FlashSets cards is One-to-Many:]

I tried to create a variable where I would store date and name of flashcards and later pass it to the set of flashcards.

At this point I'm stuck on how to use relationships to be able to create a stack of flashcards that I would store lately.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What are you talking about? The only place where `cards: [FlashCardData],` appears in the code is in a function declaration. It declares the type of the `cards` argument.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your `addName(...)` function doesn't have a return type. There's no `-> Something` at the end of the function declaration. That means it returns `Void`, that is, nothing, which the error messages represent as `()`.

Because of this:

1. Your variable `newSet` has a type of `Void`, or `()`.
2. Because of this, you can't call `addToCards` on a `newSet`, which is what the error message `Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'addToCards'.` is trying to tell you.
3. Also because of this, you can't pass `newSet` as the argument to a function that wants a `FlashSets`, which you try to do when you call  `dataController.add(...)`. This is what the error message `Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'FlashSets'` is trying to tell you.

It looks like all you need for these error messages is:

1. Add `-> FlashSets` to the end of the `addName(...)` function declaration so that the function returns a `FlashSets`.
2. Add a line at the end of `addName(...)` that reads `return data` so that the function actually does return a `FlashSets`.