# How to use relationships in CoreData to be able to access the data?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I have encountered a problem with adding data to CoreData. the logic is that when the user taps on "save" button, the program adds the data (term, definition, tag, date) to FlashCardData, and also, name and date for the set of flashcards. I have two entities since I would like to use relationships between them in order to access the data from one and to use in another. In my case, use data from FlashCardData in FlashSets in order to create a set of flashcards.

However, my approach seems to not work as I'm receiving errors regarding the usage of optionals like this: 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'FlashSets''. At this point of learning how to use CoreData I'm stuck, is there a way to solve this?
Here's the code where i'm adding data to CoreData (TermDefinitionView):

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                        // Create new FlashSets
                        
                       // currentSet = dataController.addName(name: name, date: Date(), cards: [], context: managedObjectContext)
                        let newSetOptional = dataController.addName(name: name, date: Date(), cards: [], context: managedObjectContext)
                        
                        if let newSet = newSetOptional {
                                dataController.savedFlash = []

                                // Create new FlashCardData for each term/definition/tag in viewModel.termdefpairs and associate with newSet
                                for testForm in viewModel.termdefpairs {
                                    let card = dataController.add(term: testForm.term, definition: testForm.definition, tag: testForm.tag, date: Date(), set: newSet, context: managedObjectContext)
                                    dataController.savedFlash.append(card)
                                    newSet.addToCards(card)
                                }
                                dataController.save(context: managedObjectContext)
                                
                                currentSet = newSet // Assuming currentSet is a state variable to hold the current set
                                isShowingSet = true
                                dismiss()
                            }
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                        if let currentSet = currentSet {
                            NavigationLink(destination: SetView(flashSet: currentSet, flashCardData: _flashCardData), isActive: $isShowingSet) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

DataController to handle data:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataController()
    @Published var savedFlash: [FlashCardData] = []
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData> = FlashCardData.fetchRequest()
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
        } catch {
            print("We could not save the data...")
        }
    }
    func add(term: String, definition: String, tag: String, date: Date, set: FlashSets, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> FlashCardData  {
        let data = FlashCardData(context: context)
    //    flashCardData.flashSet = flashSet
        data.id = UUID()
        data.definition = definition
        data.term = term
        data.tag = tag
        data.date = date
        data.set = set
        save(context: context)
        return data
    }
    func addName(name: String, date: Date, cards: [FlashCardData], context: NSManagedObjectContext)  -> FlashSets {
        let data = FlashSets(context: context)
        data.name = name
        data.date = date
        data.addToCards(NSSet(array: cards))
        save(context: context)
        return data
    }
```

After the button was tapped and the data added, I'm fetching it here(SetView):

```
struct SetView: View {
    
    var flashSet: FlashSets
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
   // @FetchRequest(entity: FlashCardData.entity(), sortDescriptors: NSSortDescriptor[key: ])
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date().addingTimeInterval(1) as NSDate)
    ) var flashCardData: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>
    
    let dataController = DataController.shared
    var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
    var onRemove: ((SwipeDirection) -> Void)? = nil
    @State private var isShown = false
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var label: String = "Still Learning"  // Define a label string
    @State private var showPositiveIndicator = false
    @State private var showNegativeIndicator = false
    @State private var showMiddleIndicator = false
    @State private var showEasyIndicator = false
    @State var redirectToSet = false
    var body: some View {
       
            
        if let cards = flashSet.cards?.allObjects as? [FlashCardData] {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
                Text(card.term ?? "")
            }
            // Now flashcards is an array of FlashCardData
        }
            //rest of the code...
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                    ForEach(flashCardData, id: \.self) { flashcards in
                        //   FlashcardView(flashcard: flashcard)
                        
                        SingleFlashCard(card: flashcards)
}
```

Comment: When you're getting an error message, it helps if you say what line or lines are affected by the error message, so people trying to help don't have to work at figuring out details that you already know.

Comment: sorry, the problem I have inside the NavigationLink: SetView(flashSet: currentSet, flashCardData: _flashCardData). The error is Value of optional type 'FlashSets?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'FlashSets' for flashSet: currentSet.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is:

1. You create a variable with the line reading `let newSetOptional = dataController.addName(...)`.
2. The function `addName(...)` returns a `FlashSets`. This is not an optional-- it's a `FlashSets`, not a `FlashSets?`.
3. Next you do this:

```
if let newSet = newSetOptional {
    ....
}
```

But the `if let` syntax is only valid if you're checking on an optional. Your `newSetOptional` is not an optional, but you're using optional syntax to check whether it's nil. That doesn't make sense.

You can fix this by either changing `addName(...)` to return an optional value, or by getting rid of the `if let newSet = newSetOptional`.

Additionally, between this question and [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774687/how-to-use-relationships-in-coredata-properly), it seems that you're having trouble with general Swift concepts, not with Core Data specifically. In both cases the problem and solution would have been the same whether or not you were using Core Data. If you continue to have trouble, you might find solutions more quickly by focusing on the Swift nature of the problem instead of trying to find the answer in Core Data.

Comment: thank you for your response, I see now that I'm lacking general knowledge of Swift itself.